# Split uma string

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou tentando fazer um simples código utilizando o `split`, mas esta ocorrendo alguns erros que eu não estou conseguindo resolver.. no `if` com asterisco o VBA me informa que o `subscript` esta fora do range..

```
Sub Getinstrument()
Dim instrument As String
Dim splitinstrument() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim removespax As Integer
Dim tam As Integer
removespax = -1
'Set instrument = Range(ActiveCell.Row, B)

instrument = Range("E3")
splitinstrument() = Split(instrument)
tam = Len(instrument) - 1
  For i = 0 To tam
**If splitinstrument(i) <> "" And "x" Then
    removespax = removespax + 1
    splitinstrument(removespax) = splitinstrument(i)
End If
Next
ReDim Preserve splitinstrument(removespax)
MsgBox splitinstrument()
End Sub
```

Comment: Código bem estranho... Você deveria olhar o tamanho do próprio array para percorre-lo; ao invés, você está se orientando pelo tamanho do range `instrument`. Você precisa depurar e identificar o conteúdo de `splitinstrument`. Este array pode estar vazio.

Comment: eu fiz as seguintes modificacoes no codigo

Comment: eu fiz as seguintes modificacoes no codigo               instrument = Range("E3")
splitinstrument() = Split(instrument)
    
For i = LBound(splitinstrument) To UBound(splitinstrument)
    If splitinstrument(i) <> "" Then
        removespax = removespax + 1
        splitinstrument(removespax) = splitinstrument(i)
    End If
Next                                                       eu depurei o codigo e o VBA continua dando erro no tipo do splitinstrument 'type mismatch'.  Eu tentei utilizar a funcao mid para poder separar minha string mas continuei com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Por favor, atualize sua pergunta com o novo código e informando a linha que ocorre o erro.

Answer (score 3):

No Excel, os *arrays* começam na posição 1. No trecho de código abaixo, a variável i começa com 0, e ao avaliar `splitinstrument(0)` ocorre o erro.

```
tam = Len(instrument) - 1
For i = 0 To tam
If splitinstrument(i) <> "" And "x" Then
```

Não estou em um computador com Excel para poder executar e conferir minha resposta, mas a mensagem de *Subscript out of range* indica esse tipo de problema.

A solução: alterar os índices conforme abaixo:

```
tam = Len(instrument)   ' Sem decrementar
For i = 1 To tam        ' De 1 a tam , em vez de 0 a tam-1
```